# Installing Oracle 10 ODP.NET on Microsoft Windows 2008 Server 64bit

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, oracle10g, windows-server-2008, installation

I've tried to install "**Oracle10g Release 2 ODAC (64-bit) 10.2.0.3 for Windows x64**" from:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/64-bit/index.html

on **Windows 2008 server 64bit**, but it crushes right after i run the setup.exe with the following error:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event
>   Name: APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: javaw.exe   Application
>   Version:  5.0.40.5   Application
>   Timestamp:    42a019e4   Fault Module
>   Name: StackHash_5c81   Fault Module
>   Version:  6.0.6001.18000   Fault Module
>   Timestamp:    4791adec   Exception
>   Code: c0000374   Exception
>   Offset:   00000000000a6e97   OS
>   Version:  6.0.6001.2.1.0.272.7   Locale
>   ID:   1037   Additional Information
>   1:    5c81   Additional Information
>   2:    fa1981fc0da3377cbbec45e762388188
>   Additional Information 3: 7698
>   Additional Information
>   4:    7defb6f15001721d919a359fb7888c17
>
> Read our privacy statement:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409

**can anyone direct me to a version that i can install the latesr version of ODP.NET for Windows 2008 server 64bit?**

Best regards,
Guy Bertental

Comment: i had the same problem with that install.

Answer (score 3):

It's a really tricky. Before installing ODP.NET you need to already have working connection setup to oracle database. That means:

Step 1:
Oracle install client (never succeeded with that, not recommended) or Oracle client (succeeded on Win7 ultimate 64bit, file win64_11gR1_client.zip, installed with "Runtime" option selected). After client install make sure you can connect. From command line try "tnsping yourtnanamesentry" to check if tnsnames is ok, and after that "sqlplus username/pwd@yourtnsnamesentry" to check if you know valid user and password and really can connect. Memorize or write down oracle home name and path you choosed during install.

Step 2:
Install ODP.NET (I did with file ODAC1110720.zip). Use exactly the same oracle home name, but different path during installation.

Step 3: try connecting with visual studio. For "server name" I used this: "oraclexe:1521/xe". That means I have machine called "oraclexe" which has oracle listener on port 1521, and database with instance name "xe". It's so-called "EZCONNECT" name.

I'm not sure if Step 1 is really needed or not, because maybe step3 really uses just oracle instant client.
I know, it is real pain, but this works. It took me 2 days to connect to oracle, and I had to install almost 1GB of downloaded oracle software. They could and should make that much, much, much, much easier. Like one-click install that just works. This is shame how complicated client install is.

Answer (score 1):

Donwload and install Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) on your development computer.
Delete former references to Oracle.DataAccess on your project.
Add the new reference pointing to this new version.
In Visual Studio, after adding the reference select it, then choose properties to check the setting. Set “Specific Version” true , then check that “Copy Local” is false.
Build your solution using ANY CPU target.

Next, prepare your server. Install [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win64_11gR2_client.zip) . When installing, select the RUNTIME OPTION.

Finally, deploy your solution to your server, as you always use to do. This time it should work.

The trick is to have the same ODAC version (11.2.0.1.0) on both the development and deployment enviroments. This ODAC contains the Oracle.DataAcces.Client which you should reference on your code to access classes like OracleConnection, OracleDataReader, etc.

I had problems because I had developed using ODAC 11.2.0.1.2 (32 bits, latest at this time) but there's no x64 version for this ODAC.

So, always use the latest stable ODAC version which has 32 bits and 64 bits version if you are going to develop on 32 bits and deploy on 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ran into your problem, solution is get a copy of 10204_vista_w2k8_x64_production_client.zip (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204-winx64-vista-win2k8-082253.html) run this & it will install the client.

Unpack ODAC10203x64.zip then go to All Programs->OracleHome->Oracle Installation Products & run the Universal Installer. When the installer runs at the Specify Source Location browse to the Stage directory created when you unpacked ODAC10203x64.zip then install as normal.

There is a ODAC112012.zip but this will not talk to Oracle 9 dB's so the above will resolve talking to legacy dB's.

Answer (score 0):

Guy- have a look at [this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/121999/0/), it may help. Getting Oracle client working is a pain at the best of times, x64 must make it harder.

Comment: thanks,
but this version is for 32bit and only for DOT.NET 1.x,
i need 64bit and DOT.NET 2.x version of ODP.NET

Comment: Woops- I misread it. I thought I had previously seen a post there on a similar sounding issue. Have you checked to see if there are any Oracle patch sets for this specific release?

There seems to be different patches for Itanium vs EM64T- which m ight make a difference to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had unexpected crashes in my application using Instant Client 10.2.0.3 on Windows Server 2008 x64. After reading a few posts about the lack of support for this platform, I upgraded the client to 11.1.0.7 and it works like a charm !

So I would be surprised if ODP .NET 10.2.0.3 would be stable on Windows Server 2008 x64, if you ever managed to install it. IMHO, your options are :

- use another provider (Microsoft+client v11.1, or [DataDirect](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net_for_oracle/index.ssp)...).
- go with the [11.1.0.7 beta version](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index1110710beta.html) if you dare...

Comment: The Data Direct drivers are definitely a good option. I've used them for Sybase in the past.

Comment: thanks,
how long are you using the 11.1.0.7 beta version in production?

Comment: i've checked this version, and oracle support says that if you need 64bit support you should download the "Oracle10g Release 2 ODAC (64-bit) 10.2.0.3 for Windows x64" which doesn't work on my server...

you can read the FAQ of 11.1.0.7 beta version here:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/faq.html#64-bit

Comment: I am using Oracle Instant Client 11.1.0.7 (not ODAC). ODAC v10 x64 is only supported on XP, Server 2003 : http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/faq.html#install