# migrate 32 bit web site to 64 bit (2008 r2) with oracle odac

Tags: c#, oracle11g, iis-7.5, 32bit-64bit

i have web site working well on win2003 32bit with oracle 10g, the develope is on XP 32bit with VS2005

i try to move to win2008r2 64bit with oracle 11g, but i can't get the oracle to work.

i installed the oracle client for 32bit and for 64bit

1. using the old code
2. change config file
3. enabled the 32 bit system in the IIS
   AppPoll
4. instaling the ODAC112021Xcopy_32bit

gave me this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.2.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Version=2.102.2.20 is the old assembly i used

1. removing the local
   'Oracle.DataAccess' file from the
   web/bin folder
2. installing the ODAC112021Xcopy_x64
   and the

gave me another error

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

can anyone split some light on this issue?

Tnx
Gil

Answer (score 0):

ODAC must be the same version on your development and production environment.

I'm using ODAC 11.2.0.1.0 which brings Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0 dll and it works fine.

Download 32 and 64 bit ODAC version 11.2.0.1.0. 
Install 32-bit ODAC on your development machine and 64-bit ODAC on your server.

On Visual Studio, add a reference to Oracle.DataAccess. 
Set "Specific version" to "True" and "Include local copy" to "False", so it looks for ODAC from the GAC and the same version (11.2.0.1.0) but its 64 bit equivalent on the production server.

For more information, check this answer [Installing Oracle 10 ODP.NET on Microsoft Windows 2008 Server 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862036/installing-oracle-10-odp-net-on-microsoft-windows-2008-server-64bit/4097858#4097858)